# MediaWiki respons enormously slow

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I am running a Mediawiki site on my Jetson Nano(ubuntu 18.04).

Sometime it takes a life time to load, but as soon as i refresh the page, or open another tab with the same address, the page can be loaded instantly.

Same thing happened inside Mediawiki site, I have to double click links or refresh it to get a fast load.

My apache forwarding directory has an index.html of AriaNG, so i put mediawiki in $apachedirectory/wiki.
There is also an index.html of Tiddlywiki in $apachedirectory/tiddly.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )

Zend Engine v3.2.0

Mysql Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

I am kinda new here, so if there is anything i should not do or i should to improve the quality of my question, please, do point it out. Thx

Comment: Have you checked your server response time?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, I have Filerun, Tiddlywiki and AriaNG on that server, each response instantly.